# Translating a meme, #1: "Hey buddy"

Tags: joke

I've had the idea for a while that translating English-language memes to send to my Korean mother might be fun. I'd enjoy learning about the nuances of Korean language and she'd at least know I'm thinking of her, even if the memes don't hit right.

The meme that originally gave me this idea is this one:

[image]

I was born in the US and only learned rudimentary Korean as a child in the 90s (speaking to my mom and reading some books), but here's what I've got so far.

- **Center:** Starting here seemed easiest. But the only thing I could think of was, "야, 임마".
- **Yellow:** Which does work for starting fights, which in turn might be "싸움을 시작할때," or is there a better vernacular?
- **Blue:** But it doesn't really work with consoling a child, right? At least, not a very young one, which "a child" sort of implies. I can imagine a father saying it to a son though, so maybe this one has to change to "아들 한태"?
- **Pink:** And I have no idea what Koreans say to their pets, but I said "야, 임마" to my dog just now and he didn't seem to mind...
- **Orange:** I think "밖에 나갈래" works?
- **Green:** I think "엄마 부를래" works?
- **Purple:** I also have no idea for this one.

Please do correct my spelling so I learn, and feel free suggest alternative translations and conjugations that would work better.

I also want this to be fun and welcome content in this SE, so I'll see how this one goes, listen to any feedback, and spread out future requests.

Answer (score 2):

- Center: "옳지" or "어이 친구" or "이놈"

---

- Orange: "밖에 나갈까?"
- Purple: "우쭈쭈쭈쭈"
- Green: "엄마한테 이를 거니?"

---

- Yellow: "싸움 걸기"
- Pink: "강아지 쓰다듬기"
- Blue: "아이 달래기"

Answer (score 1):

center : in korean, 야 인마 usually used informal situation. and it usually used with same sexual. like dude or mate. In this situation, speaker want to start the sentence. so i think 저기...... is more suitable,

yellow , blue and pink both describe circumstance.
yellow : correct
blue : 아들 한태 means "to son". in this situation,  아이를 데리고 다닐때 is correct
pink : i think this situation. korean used word "skinship" it`s mean physical-touch(To express affection) so you can translate it into "애완동물과 스킨십 할때"

orange : formal ways, you`re translate is work. but this is the meme so i think "일단 나가서 이야기하자"is more humorous.  It's a typical cliche when you're having an argument in korea. and it`s superficial meaning is go to the outside. so it`s also reasonable translate.

purple : i think "귺귽긂긄긆귻귾긃긅~~!"is work. in this situation, child and animal is so loud. so you can translate any language except for an understandable language.

green : i think "어머니는 어디 가셨니?"is work. You can use these words to a child who is lost. but in fighting situation, it is used to ridicule Mama Boys. And it`s polite to speak, so it feels more sarcastic.

Comment: I am 100% sure that no one would say 저기... to their dog. Also, I think none of the situations above are formal, so 야 인마 (or simply 야) is actually not a bad choice.